# Print button not visible in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have a report viewer that shows a **remote** report. But when the report is loaded i can't see the print,refresh buttons. The same thing happens on the server PC when i try to check my reports in the report manager. (Used Chrome,Firefox)

Here is a screenshot the toolbar where the buttons should be.

[image]

This my reportviewer starting tag code. (The buttons are all "true" to be visible)

```
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" CssClass="reportviewer" Font-Names="Verdana" BorderColor="Black" ShowBackButton="true" ShowPrintButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="true"
        BorderStyle="None" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true" 
        WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="1050px" Width="900px" ProcessingMode="Remote">
```

I have tried to fix this problem by installing **ReportViewer Redistributable pack 2010** in both my development PC and the server. I tested both local and remote reports but it's the same on both cases.

How can i fix it?

Environment: SQL Server 2012 64 bit; IDE: VISUAL STUDIO 2010;

**NOTE 1 : The refresh button is visible when i remove all of the css references. (Thanx @DJ KRAZE  for pointing that)**

**NOTE 2 : Just checked the new CSS rules and the print button is visible in IE.**

Comment: you are showing the refresh button in the image above..is there some sort of `Div` issue what does the aspx code for that particular region look like..?

Comment: the refresh button is css/div problem ... i will fix it soon... but an you tell me what to do with the printing button?

Comment: Can you list the `Browser(s)` that you are working with this on or have tried this on..?

Comment: (Used Chrome,Firefox and IE)

Comment: In IE now i can see the print button :D

Comment: is there a `hasprintbutton=true` property that you can use or add

Comment: There is `ShowPrintButton="true"` in the start tag for the reportviewer

Comment: I know that but there is also a `hasprintbutton=true` setting you can use if I am not mistaken

Comment: I am afraid that i haven't found anything like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2009/02/27/manually-printing-a-report.aspx) is a class in Brian **Hartman's Report Viewer Blog** that can print both local and server reports.

Just create a button or a image button and use it like this in the onclick method to print from any browser.

```
  ReportPrintDocument rp = new ReportPrintDocument(ReportViewer1.ServerReport);
  rp.Print();
```

Answer (score 6):

Print button is hidden in any browser that is not IE because ReportViewer uses ActiveX for client printing which means no other browser other than IE can handle it.